# IAT hook on MessageBoxA - The function keep calling each other

Tags: c, winapi, hook, dllimport, portable-executable

I didn't quite understand what is happening, but i'll explain the problem.
I'm trying to write an IAT hook program, which switches the address of the MessageBoxA function in the IAT so that it points to my function, a malicious one.

Below is my code, commented:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int(__stdcall* FunctionLikeMessageBoxA) (HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType);

FunctionLikeMessageBoxA originalMsgBoxA = MessageBoxA; // the original MessageBoxA function, before IAT hooking.


int print_evil(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    printf("Evil print");
    Sleep(1000);

    return originalMsgBoxA(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
}

int main()
{
    // message box before IAT unhooking
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Before Hooking", "Before Hooking", 0);

    LPVOID imageBase = GetModuleHandleA(NULL); // image base, start of the loaded code (?)
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)imageBase; // dos headers
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + dosHeaders->e_lfanew); // ntHeaders are in e_lfanew

    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR importDescriptor = NULL;
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY importsDirectory = ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT]; // IAT
    importDescriptor = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(importsDirectory.VirtualAddress + (DWORD_PTR)imageBase); // img descriptor

    LPCSTR currentLibraryName = NULL;
    HMODULE loadedLibrary = NULL;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME functionName = NULL;

    while (importDescriptor->Name != NULL) // run until library name is not null, meaning we have libraries
    {

        currentLibraryName = (LPCSTR)importDescriptor->Name + (DWORD_PTR)imageBase; // get name of library
        loadedLibrary = LoadLibraryA(currentLibraryName); // loading the dll library

        if (loadedLibrary)
        {
            PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA originalFirstThunk = NULL;
            PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA firstThunk = NULL;

            // thunk where the functions are located  (?)
            originalFirstThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + importDescriptor->OriginalFirstThunk); // the INT (Names)
            firstThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + importDescriptor->FirstThunk); // the IAT (Addresses)

            while (originalFirstThunk->u1.AddressOfData != NULL) // run until function name is not null, meaning we have functions
            {

                functionName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + originalFirstThunk->u1.AddressOfData); // name of function

                // if name is MessageBoxA, what we need, then switch the Function address of the function in the IAT, to our function.
                if (strcmp(functionName->Name, "MessageBoxA") == 0)
                {
                    DWORD oldProtect = 0;

                    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)(&firstThunk->u1.Function), 8, PAGE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);

                    firstThunk->u1.Function = (DWORD_PTR)print_evil;

                    DWORD newProtect = 0;

                    VirtualProtect((LPVOID)(&firstThunk->u1.Function), 8, oldProtect, &newProtect);

                }

                // increase to go over the next functions.
                originalFirstThunk++;
                firstThunk++;

            }
        }

        // increase to go over the next dlls.
        importDescriptor++;

    }

    // after IAT hooking
    MessageBoxA(0, "Hello", "Hello msg", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The code is supposed to print "evil print" once. But it just keeps on printing it over and over again (I added the sleep(1000) so it doesn't buffer overflow from too much prints...).

My guess is that the `MessageBoxA` at the bottom actually calls the `print_evil` function, and the `print_evil` function calls itself over and over again.

I don't have any idea for a solution. Any help would be appreciated!

The code is supposed to print "evil print" once. But it just keeps on printing it over and over again (I added the sleep(1000) so it doesn't buffer overflow from too much prints...).

Comment: `originalMsgBoxA` points at the thunk that points to the original function. Then you update the thunk. So `originalMsgBoxA` now calls your new function. Why are you hooking the IAT manually instead of using an established hooking library like Microsoft's Detours?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - this is not exactly true. if build with optimization `originalMsgBoxA` must point to code of `MessageBoxA`. `originalMsgBoxA = MessageBoxA` equal to `originalMsgBoxA = __imp_MessageBoxA` and inside `PVOID __imp_MessageBoxA` was address of function, not thunk. but probably compliler generate stub for `MessageBoxA` - `jmp __imp_MessageBoxA` and inside `originalMsgBoxA` was address of this stub (jmp) function, which used modified `__imp_MessageBoxA`

Comment: @RbMm "*probably compliler generate stub for MessageBoxA*" - you are describing the same thing that I described, just using a different term for it (stub vs thunk).

Comment: @RemyLebeau probably. but compiler generate this thunks think only in case Edit and Continue (`/INCREMENTAL` ) option or when function declared without `DECLSPEC_IMPORT` option. but messgaboxa have it. so i think need remove `/INCREMENTAL`

Comment: To get around this use GetProcAddress to get the original function pointer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can't entirely agree with you there, from my experience, IAT hooking is "safer" compared to Detours - which uses inline hooking and thus need to disassemble the opcodes to save the instructions needed to be patched, making it more error-prone. Also, some applications perform integrity checks to detect inline but not IAT hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You assign the address of former 'MessageBox()' statically at compiler stage.
The real address is assigned by the loader when the program is committed in memory.

Move assignment in execution flow as below:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (__stdcall * FunctionLikeMessageBoxA) (HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType);
FunctionLikeMessageBoxA originalMsgBoxA = NULL; // the original MessageBoxA function, before IAT hooking.

int print_evil(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    printf("Evil print");
    Sleep(1000);

    return originalMsgBoxA(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    originalMsgBoxA = MessageBoxA;  // Assign here the original MessageBoxA function.
    // message box before IAT unhooking
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Before Hooking", "Before Hooking", 0);

    LPVOID imageBase = GetModuleHandleA(NULL);  // image base, start of the loaded code (?)
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeaders = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)imageBase;    // dos headers
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + dosHeaders->e_lfanew);    // ntHeaders are in e_lfanew

    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR importDescriptor = NULL;
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY importsDirectory = ntHeaders->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];  // IAT
    importDescriptor = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR) (importsDirectory.VirtualAddress + (DWORD_PTR)imageBase); // img descriptor

    LPCSTR currentLibraryName = NULL;
    HMODULE loadedLibrary = NULL;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME functionName = NULL;

    while (importDescriptor->Name != 0) // run until library name is not null, meaning we have libraries
    {

        currentLibraryName = (LPCSTR)importDescriptor->Name + (DWORD_PTR)imageBase; // get name of library
        loadedLibrary = LoadLibraryA(currentLibraryName);   // loading the dll library

        if (loadedLibrary)
        {
            PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA originalFirstThunk = NULL;
            PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA firstThunk = NULL;

            // thunk where the functions are located  (?)
            originalFirstThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA) ((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + importDescriptor->OriginalFirstThunk); // the INT (Names)
            firstThunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA) ((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + importDescriptor->FirstThunk); // the IAT (Addresses)

            while (originalFirstThunk->u1.AddressOfData != 0)   // run until function name is not null, meaning we have functions
            {

                functionName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME) ((DWORD_PTR)imageBase + originalFirstThunk->u1.AddressOfData);   // name of function

                // if name is MessageBoxA, what we need, then switch the Function address of the function in the IAT, to our function.
                if (strcmp(functionName->Name, "MessageBoxA") == 0)
                {
                    DWORD oldProtect = 0;

                    VirtualProtect((LPVOID) (&firstThunk->u1.Function), 8, PAGE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);

                    firstThunk->u1.Function = (DWORD_PTR)print_evil;

                    DWORD newProtect = 0;

                    VirtualProtect((LPVOID) (&firstThunk->u1.Function), 8, oldProtect, &newProtect);

                }

                // increase to go over the next functions.
                originalFirstThunk++;
                firstThunk++;

            }
        }

        // increase to go over the next dlls.
        importDescriptor++;

    }

    // after IAT hooking
    MessageBoxA(0, "Hello", "Hello msg", 0);
    return 0;
}
```